# Enigma data pack in the Royal Hotel's ballroom is inaccessible

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I am almost at 100% collection of the Enigma data packs. The particular one (shown below) is supposed to be collected by using the Batclaw after clearing the cryptographic sequencer.

[image: x]

As can be seen, I have decrypted the console, and yet the data pack is not visible. The following is showing it in detective vision:

[image: y]

Is it a bug? Would I have to restart the game from 0 to get back to 100% enigma collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is mentioned in this walktrough:

> Inside the West Tower Ballroom, in the Royal Hotel. You must glide over to a wooden platform in the center of the room. Hack the keypad, and it will reveal the datapack.

[The link to the video](https://youtu.be/Nk_EHYF2pKk?t=864) the explicit process on how to get the pack

NOTE: People have [reported](https://community.wbgames.com/t5/Arkham-Knight-Support/An-old-data-pack-glitch-in-the-ballroom/td-p/204312) that this was/is a bug that people have experienced. If this is the case, I suggest loading an older save file (I can't remember if that is possible)